# Generate point layer (grid values) with Z coordinate of (TIN) interpolated raster in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

### 1. Question With Additional Information:

I would like to generate a sparsely packed layer containing points labelled with the Z-column of an existing interpolated TIN raster

A sample photograph what is needed is attached below,

[image: Grid values overlaid over the interpolated layer - Image obtained using Surfer (Golden Software)]

### 2. Background Information:

The following explains my process flow,

Step 1. Raw data in the form of .csv files; one of which contains

(i) depth measurements at various locations from, say, a water body, i.e., 3 columns of latitude, longitude, and altitude (altitude represents the Z-column described in the question), and the other.

(ii) boundary of the area covered previous explained in (i); again in latitude, longitude and Z-column form.

Step 2. Generate .shp files using OSGeo and GeoPandas - Python of items in *Step 1* (along with the required CRS).

Step 3. Using ***TIN interpolation*** to generate raster of item described as *(i)* in *Step 1*.

Step 4. Use ***Clip Raster by Mask Layer*** to remove extents beyond the boundary described in (ii) in *Step 1*. The function, ***minimum bounding geometry*** is used to create the required mask layer from the boundary layer csv file.

### 3. Step of Interest Wherein the Question Asked Arises:

Step 5. I, now, use ***Pixels to Points*** to generate the point layer and further, add *Labels*->*Single Labels*-> Select the column containing the Z-column. However, the result obtained is very densely packed that the underlying layer is no longer visible. This is described in the image below,

[image]

How can I modify the density/ resolution/ the number of points to achieve a result close to that described in the Image in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wm9.png)?

Comment: Create a new grid, drape (set z value from raster)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The only problem with creating a new grid with extents and setting a Z value using drape is that I am unable to find a way to clip off the points which don't fall within the layer clipped using *Step 4* (using extents gives me only a rectangular shaped grid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial detailing an alternative to solve this problem but in spanish here https://acolita.com/etiquetado-inteligente-de-puntos-en-qgis-3/

I describe you the most important aspects

You can achieve what you want by setting a filter on the labels. Open the layer properties dialog box or the Layers > Symbology panel.

[image]

Set up a ruler-based symbology, for each ruler assign a filter using expressions and the scale ranges in which it will be visible. Set rulers for each scale range, points look close together at a small scale but separate at a larger scale, so you must assign rulers for each case.

[image]

For example, we can use the following option, using the id of each record.  You write the following expression to display only each 25 points $id % 25 = 0

Assign as many rulers as you need considering the density of your points and evaluating how they look at different scales.

For the case of the example I developed use

- Scales < 1:60.000 will be displayed every 25 points.
- Scale between 1:60.000 and 1:25.000, will be shown every 20 points.
- Scales between 1:25.000 and 1:10.000, displayed every 5 points
- Scales larger than 1:10.000, all points are displayed.

[image]

The result looks like this

[image]

The dots remain with a fixed, regular spacing, you can try other expressions that give you a random effect, for example you can use the expression rand

**there is a way to configure rules to achieve this result through the distance between two points?**

If your points are irregularly scattered and you want to show only the points with neighboring points not too close to each other on a small scale

You can configure the rule filter with buffering for example, define a minimum distance threshold up to which you accept to see points close to that scale you can use an aggregate expression

**Warning**: this is very demanding and may take some time because the expressions are not optimized.

Parameters:

- **Point layer name**: points
- **Distance threshold chosen**: 100

**Expression:**
aggregate(layer:='points', aggregate:='count', expression:=$id, filter:=intersects(buffer($geometry, 100,5), geometry(@parent))))

Comment: Thank you for your answer - your suggestions work well! However, it seems that my points are not regularly spaced and hence, the end-result is also not regularly spaced. Perhaps there is a way to configure rules to achieve this result through the distance between two points?

Comment: Interesting question!!! if you can do it, you can do it with an added expression, I updated the answer with the details. I will update the blog article soon too :D